# can't find textView id inside toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am working with a simple application on android where at the moment i net to create a toolbar so i created a custom toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**then i included this custom layout on my activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.FamilyLibrary">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="#f1c40f"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="562dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Familias"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>
```

when i try to setText on my activity for the TextView, i fails and i get this error:                                                                                           `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

**here is my code on the activity:**

```
  Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);;
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        TextView toolbarText = (TextView) myToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbarText.setText("Famílias");
```

Any tip?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving two different id to toolbar layout

```
 android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
```

and in main layout while including you are giving

```
 <include
    layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
```

make these ids same

Comment: nice catch, final of the day, could not catch that :/, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you don't need to call `findViewById()` on your toolbar, you should just be able to use this: `findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title)`

Your code should end up looking like this:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
TextView toolbarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
toolbarText.setText("Famílias");
```